# Succinct message to clearly direct user to check a box

Tags: conversion

I have a payment form, and part of it by default, asks your email address, but above that it currently has a question:

Returning Customer?

with two buttons Yes/No, which look a little ambiguous as to which is checked. I wanted to go back to something more basic, with just a standard checkbox, but was wondering what I could say to make it clear, some examples are:

- Check if returning customer
- Existing customers check box

But I don't like saying check in the text, it sounds like you are trying too hard. Any ideas what would be the aptly fitting text to describe the action?

I should have started with this, here is the image of them currently, as you can see it is not clear enough between the YES and NO[image]

So they are tabs.

Comment: the state of the checkbox will change anything else on the form? (something depends on the value of that checkbox?)

Comment: it will remove the sign up email and phone, and change those fields to username and password login.

Answer (score 8):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgyXcy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

:)

Comment: this. simple and to the point

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox state modifies the form, you could reflect that hierachy by using a different control. Tabs could let the user choose between two different forms instead.

[image: The Verge login]

Source: [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/)

Or provide two forms.

[image: Apple login]

[Source](https://econsultancy.com/blog/65467-guest-checkout-test-which-of-these-30-uk-retailers-force-users-to-register/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Yes/No I'd suggest putting the labels on each option:

- Returning Customer
- Guest

and have one selected by default.

Comment: thats the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I like @vitaly's answer, but the rest of your proposed solution I think needs work. What's the difference between an 'Account email' and an 'Email address'? I suggest they're the same thing, so use the same term. Why are you collecting a phone number for delivery rather than a password? It seems to me that you could use the same form for both parties: I suspect a new user would need to enter a password, so consider giving them the option to register at the same time - still an email address and password, just used to create a new account.

Comment: Password is generated randomly.

Comment: @source doesn't that make it harder for the user to remember, or do they then need to go and change it in another step?

Comment: they can change it in their account. I just want to make it as easy for them so it converts better.